Why is our VS2022 IISExpress web project running as SSL without SSL enabled in launchSettings.json
We are running a VS2022 / .NET 6.0 web project (migrated over various .net core versions) on IISExpress, using the standard Visual Studio self-signed SSL mechanism.
All of a sudden, when I start the project through CTRL-F5, the browser navigates to the http://localhost:65067 in stead of the proper SSL-based url. This redirects to https://localhost (no port number, I assume HSTS) and a "connection refused" error.
The settings do indeed show that the SSL checkbox is off, and turning it on resolves the problem for me.

However, none of my project mates have to do this, and we are all on exact the same launchSettings.json (sslport: 0).
Is there any other VS config mechanism which is causing them to still succesfully run SSL? Has this e.g. been moved from the applicationhost.config (not in version control) to launchSettings.json in some recent VS2022 update?

VS2022 is still evolving, but there isn't enough documentation on what exactly has changed (or will change) behind the scene on everything around ASP.NET Core. What I feel so far is that .NET projects in VS are moving away from IIS/IIS Express (no default setting to host on IIS Express), and stick more to Kestrel directly. HTTPS is also be removed from the development settings to avoid unnecessary noises because in the end you configure HTTPS on the web servers, not Kestrel. (HTTP to HTTPS redirection is also removed from default I think.)
